# Ubuntu SFTP Client with sudo capability

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, sftp

Recently I completely switched to Ubuntu for my work computer. But I have one problem. On Windows I used WinSCP to connect to remove development server via SFTP and I can't find any app for Ubuntu that would work for me here. The problem is not the SFTP itself - I can connect to the server without any problems - however I need to login as unprivileged user and then run sudo to be able to traverse into directories my unprivileged user can't access.

In WinSCP I could configure my *WinSCP server* as `sudo su -c /bin/sftp-server` and as *shell* I had to put `sudo su -`.

Is there any app that can connect to SFTP in simmiliar matter like WinSCP could on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you like the GUI-ness of WinSCP, then try something like Filezilla.  It's available on ubuntu with `sudo apt install filezilla`.  It supports the SFTP protocol.

In terms of being able to access the files you need, this is a server configuration issue.  If things can only be accessed via `root`, then simply `sftp` as user `root`.

It's possible this won't work.  It's common for `sshd` servers to be configured with `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` or `PermitRootLogin no`.  In that case you should do something server-side.  It sounds like you already have the root password, so this should be possible.

Idea 1:  Ensure the files are owned by your user, or at least world-readable.  If you need to send files to a directory, ensure those directories are owned by your user or world-writable.  This is the best solution as you shouldn't need full root permission for simple file-server access.

Idea 2: If `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`, Add your public `ssh` key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the server at `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  Then ensure your client (Filezilla) uses your private ssh key.

Idea 3: If `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has `PermitRootLogin no`, change it to `PermitRootLigin prohibit-password`, `sudo systemctl restart sshd`, then continue with Idea 2.

Idea 4: In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, set `PermitRootLogin yes` and then `sudo systemctl restart sshd`.  Then you can login as user `root` using `root`'s password.  This is the least secure because people can try to guess the password. This is also the easiest solution.